# Can a string be converted to a string containing escape sequences in Java?

Tags: java, string, file, formatting, escaping

Say I enter a string:-

```
Hello
Java!
```

I want the output as:-

```
Hello\nJava!
```

Is there any way in which I could get the output in this format?
I am stuck on this one and not able to think about any logic which could do this for me.

Comment: Enter a String where? You will have to append a `"\n"` while building the String.

Comment: Yeah! you're right. Even if I use Scanner class then also it will take a single line only. So what should I do? Any suggestions? Using file or something else. I'm very confused with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html does what you want.

EG

```
String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(String str)
```

Will return "Hello\nJava!" when supplied with your string.

Answer (score 1):

Hm..You can replace the new line character(`\n`) with `\\n`. For example:

```
String helloWithNewLine = "Hello\nJava";
String helloWithoutNewLine = helloWithNewLine.replace("\n", "\\n");
System.out.println(helloWithoutNewLine);
```

Output:

```
Hello\nJava
```

Comment: sir this was not my question.